# Install microsoft access 1.x on windows xp

Tags: windows, ms-access

I want to install access 1.x to open a mdb file of that type, but I can't install the program and it give me this error:

> "install a Windows for Workgroups driver"

Somewhere in internet I find that you need to install from a diskette the odbc:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS_Access/Q_22103622.html

but I can't find that diskette nowhere!
What can I do? how can I open this mdb file?

Comment: Don't... make.... it... worse.... with... a.... snarky.... comment....

Comment: Access 1.x dates from 1992. It was designed for 16 bit Windows 3.1. You have no chance of installing it on XP.

Comment: Ok, how about Access 2.0, can i install it on xp?

Comment: Just guessing, how about an emulator http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/83362-35-emulator?

Comment: what version(s) of access do you have available? some of the newer ones will read the old data.

Comment: I already tried with access 2010, but it give me the error that i can't open files that wasn't made with access 2010.
In access 2007 it says that the mdb it's previous to odbc.
¿There is a way to know the tables that are inside this file?

Comment: May be of interest: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/looking-convert-access-10-mdb-30112.aspx OR http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-unable-open-access-1-x-file-t1068111.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, today early morning, i was trying again with this and found that you can import the database using access 2007, like it written in this forum:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-unable-open-access-1-x-file-t1068111.html

"Create a blank database and then use the import feature in the Tables to import the old mdb object.
You may need to do little reformatting but you will see most of the data."

It add you the tables in the new database.

Thanks for the help :D.